# running partcover on a 64 bit machine generates 1KB output file

Tags: ccnet-config, partcover

When i run the partcover from the console on a 32 bit machine, i am getting 5 mb file generated as output. But when i ran the same on 64 bit machine's commmand prompt i am getting 1 KB file as the output.

I have used

> CorFlags.exe PartCover.exe /32BIT+
>   /Force 
>   CorFlags.exe PartCover.Browser.exe /32BIT+
>   /Force

But no able to generate a proper output. I am using Nunit 2.5 and Part Cover 2.3

Comment: FYI: There is now a new code coverage tool (beta) called [OpenCover][1] it has 32 and 64 bit support.


  [1]: https://github.com/sawilde/opencover

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used PartCover with NUnit on a 64 bit machine, but it often requires some fiddling to get working. One of the key things for me was to ensure that the tests were being run using **nunit-console-x86.exe**.

I recommend using the most recent version of PartCover, which is a fork on GitHub -  [PartCover.NET 4](https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4) and read [this](http://alexhumphrey.me.uk/unit-testing/partcover-pitfalls-with-nunit-on-windows-7-x64/) and [this](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2009/10/15/get-partcover-running-on-x64-windows/).